# How to display first category of custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show first category of my custom post type in my {post-type}-single.php page. this is my code:

```html
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
the_post(); ?>

<div class="breadcrumb main">
 <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a> > <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?> > <?php the_title();?>
</div>

<?php } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

Comment: How do you want to determine the first category? Is it by alphabetical order?